# How to edit a hardcoded string in compiled DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, decompiling, il

I have a single compiled dll which i need to change a little. It was written by me half a year ago, but I've lost the source code. There's one single hardcoded string in it (it's a filename)

I need to change it from `TestPage.html` to `TestPage1.html` (it's not much longer)

**How to do that?** The string is anonymous, the corresponding piece of code is:

```
... + folder + "TestPage.html"
```

There's no variable it's assigned to.

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT: I do not want to recompile c# code after extracting it with Reflector-like tools!*

Comment: If you don't want to recompile C# code after extracting it then decompile to IL instead - either way the answer that abatishchev has posted **is** the correct way of doing this

Comment: If you don't want to recompile, you ran out of options.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php), which provides a very raw view on .NET assemblies. It also provides the possibility to view and even modify the UserString-stream (find it under `.NET Directory > MetaData Streams > #US`).

The UserString-stream stores string literals as the one you described. You should be able to find your particular string with the find-function and modify it. However, there is a limitation: You cannot use a string with a different length (shorter or longer). This would mess up the indices of all strings that would follow later on in the UserString-stream and all the offsets of the other sections. So, unfortunately I think changing it to `TestPage1.html` will not work, as it is one character longer.

Comment: Works like a charm - I just added an empty space (code 00) and it fixed my problem anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Use Reflector (or other similar tool) to decompile IL into C# (or another CLR language), and then - edit and compile it again.

Comment: I can't. Its code is rather complicated dll: with a lot of anonymous functions, files, partial classes in it.

Comment: @IlyaSmagin Why not?  Even if you can't decompile to C# that builds you can definitely decompile to IL that builds.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the free tool [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to decompile the code and ressources from a .NET-dll file.

Comment: And how exactly this would help me with my problem?